# How to close a auto generated iframe in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How i can close a iframe that is automatically generated in Java. I am trying to first find it through the XPath is it good or there is another way for this??

```
WebElement ifr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='loginIframe']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(ifr); //Switch to iFrame

System.out.println(driver.switchTo().frame(ifr).getTitle());
System.out.println(ifr.getAttribute("name"));
```

Now I am getting "Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it " error. Please tell a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

After you switch to frame

```
WebElement ifr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='loginIframe']"));
  driver.switchTo().frame(ifr);
```

Try to switch back with:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();}
```